Using awk and inverse grep for specific columns across files
Assume a tab-separated file as input file 1 ($IN1):
$ cat input1.tsv
HEAD1   HEAD2   HEAD3   HEAD4   HEAD5   HEAD6
Qux ZX_999876   Bar Foo MN111111    Quux
Foo AB_123456   Bar Baz CD789123    Qux
Bar AC_456321   Baz Qux GF333444    Foo
Foo CD789123    Qux Baz GH987124    Qux

Further assume a csv-separated file as input file 2 ($IN2):
$ cat input2.csv
AB_123456,CD789123
ZX_999876,MN111111

Input file 2 specifies which lines of input file 1 need to be deleted. Specifically, if column 1 entry of input file 2 is equal to the column 2 entry of input file 1, then all lines of input file 1 in which column 2 entry of input file 2 is equal to the column 2 entry of input file 1 are to be removed.
Desired output:
$ cat input1_filtered.tsv
HEAD1   HEAD2   HEAD3   HEAD4   HEAD5   HEAD6
Qux ZX_999876   Bar Foo MN111111    Quux
Foo AB_123456   Bar Baz CD789123    Qux
Bar AC_456321   Baz Qux GF333444    Foo

I wish to achieve the desired output via Bash.
My (so far insufficient) attempt:
while IFS=, read -r CL1 CL2
do
    if awk -F"\t" '$2=="$CL1"' $IN1
    then
        grep -vPw "(?<=\t)$CL2" $IN1 > tmp.txt
        mv tmp.txt $IN1
    fi
done < $IN2


You've already employed awk, why not solve the whole task with it?

@pmf Would love to. How do I do it?

You're just testing whether awk got an error, not whether it matched anything.

for the first file (input1.tsv) ... are HEAD2 values unique within the file or could they occur more than once? if they can occur more than once then which line should we remove  ... 1st occurrence? last occurrence? all occurrences? based an a value in another column? something else?

This uses GNU awk specifically:

process input2.csv, storing the mapping
process input1.tsv, determining if col1 of input2.csv is present
process input1.tsv a second time, filtering out the unwanted records

gawk '
    BEGINFILE   { FS = ARGIND == 1 ? "," : "\t" }
    ARGIND == 1 { is_present[$1] = $2; next }
    ARGIND == 2 { if ($2 in is_present) del[is_present[$2]] = 1; next }
    !($2 in del)
' input2.csv input1.tsv input1.tsv

outputs
HEAD1   HEAD2   HEAD3   HEAD4   HEAD5   HEAD6
Qux ZX_999876   Bar Foo MN111111    Quux
Foo AB_123456   Bar Baz CD789123    Qux
Bar AC_456321   Baz Qux GF333444    Foo

ref: ARGIND, BEGINFILE

Your solution is easy to read/comprehend and extremely fast. Thank you!

Here is an awk solution that does the job in 2 pass with any awk version:
cat filt.awk

FNR == NR {
   vals[$1] = $2
   next
}
$2 in vals {
   notNeeded[ vals[$2] ]
}
{
   row[FNR] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=FNR; ++i) {
      split(row[i], tok, FS)
      if ( !(tok[2] in notNeeded) )
         print row[i]
   }
}

Then use it as:
awk -F, -f filt.awk input2.csv FS='\t' input1.tsv

HEAD1   HEAD2   HEAD3   HEAD4   HEAD5   HEAD6
Qux ZX_999876   Bar Foo MN111111    Quux
Foo AB_123456   Bar Baz CD789123    Qux
Bar AC_456321   Baz Qux GF333444    Foo


Assumptions:

in the first file (input.tsv) the HEAD2 values are unique within the file so ...
when it comes to removing a line we will find either 0 or 1 match (ie, there will never be 2+ matches)

One awk idea requiring a single pass through each input file:
awk '
FNR==1  { FS = (FNR==NR) ? "," : "\t"         # 1st file uses "," as delimiter; 2nd file uses "\t" as delimiter
          $0=$0                               # force awk to reparse based on new FS
        }
FNR==NR { keypair[$1] = $2                                  # 1st file: save key pairs
          next                                              # skip to next line of input
        }
        { line[FNR] = $0                                    # 2nd file: save line based on line number (FNR)
          key_to_line[$2] = FNR                             # save relationship between key and line number
        }
END     { for (key in keypair)                              # for each key in our pairs of keys ...
              if (key in key_to_line)                       # if there is an input line with this key then ...
                 delete line[key_to_line[keypair[key]]]     # delete the line (if it exists) which contains the 2nd half of our key pair

          for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)                             # print the lines that remain
              if (i in line)
                 print line[i]
        }
' input2.csv input1.tsv

NOTE: this assumes both files can fit into memory
This generates:
HEAD1   HEAD2   HEAD3   HEAD4   HEAD5   HEAD6
Qux ZX_999876   Bar Foo MN111111    Quux
Foo AB_123456   Bar Baz CD789123    Qux
Bar AC_456321   Baz Qux GF333444    Foo

